# How to innerHTML a function with array as parameter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach, innerhtml

I am learning about looping thorugh arrays - I want to pass the result of an if else statement in the forEach function (inside another function with array as parameter) to HTML using innerHTML (does not have to be innerHTML if you know better methods I do not mind). It checks if number are even and should return true and false. My result is undefined, but in console.log I can see that the loop is working. At the bottom I left "What in here" as I do not know how to select it properly.

Any help is welcome, including rebuilding the code.

```
var myArray = function (nums) {

    var average = 0;
    var totalSum = 0;

    nums.forEach(function (value) {
        //returns total sum
        totalSum = totalSum + value;

        //return average
        average = totalSum / nums.length;

        //return true if at least one even if not false
        if (value % 2 === 0) {
            console.log(value + " true");
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log(value + " false");
            return false;
        };

    })

    console.log("Total sum: " + totalSum);
    console.log("Average: " + average);
    console.log("Max number: " + Math.max.apply(null, nums));
    //document.getElementById("array").innerHTML = /*What in here?!*/
};


myArray([1, 1, 1, 2])
```

Comment: *I want to pass the result of a forEach function* - `forEach` doesn't return anything. It is to call functions which may have side-effects

Comment: Hmm... Maybe if was not clear - in the forEach you have an if statement - which I want to display. How then should I display in HTML in div id="array" - false or true?

Comment: Your myArray function does not have a return statement... That would be why it returns undefined

Comment: It has got a return statement in the forEach function in the if/else statement. How can I get to it and pass it to HTML?

Comment: What exactly do you want to see in the HTML can you give us an example of the desired output?

Comment: In the HTML i would like to see true if the arrays has got an even number or false if it hasn't got one. Is this the proper usage of return true/false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take a variable for the occurrence of even or odd numbers.

```
var myArray = function (nums) {
    var average = 0;
    var totalSum = 0;
    var hasEven = false; // flag if at least one value is even => true, otherwise false
    nums.forEach(function (value) {
        totalSum = totalSum + value;
        hasEven = hasEven || !(value % 2);
    });
    average = totalSum / nums.length; // just call it once
    console.log("Total sum: " + totalSum);
    console.log("Average: " + average);
    console.log("Max number: " + Math.max.apply(null, nums));
    console.log("Contains at least one even value: " + hasEven);
};
myArray([1, 1, 1, 2]);
```

Comment: So you create an empty array evenOdd and the add elements to it? How to make the function to print only one true if there is one even and one false otherwise?

Comment: where do you want the printout? in the loop or outside at the end of the function?

Comment: I was just wondering how to get the result to print true or false only once, when the condition is met or not. So the result to be in this case "true" instead of "false,false,false,true"

Comment: ok, i understand. if one value is odd, then true otherwise false.

Comment: great!! But could you explain me this construction: evenOdd = evenOdd || !(value % 2), please?

Comment: Actually it is `hasEven = hasEven || !(value % 2);` the assignment takes the original value of `hasEven` and performs an logical OR with the result of an inverted modulo operation. The inversion give a true when the number is odd. otherwise it returns false. In combination with OR, a possible true remains.

Answer (score -1):

An easy way would be to use [JSON.Stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
document.getElementById("array").innerHTML = JSON.Stringify(nums);
```

Comment: Can you explain why I got down voted?  I think this is a valid answer to the problem